# Apache Storm: storm-core build failure

Tags: maven, build, apache-storm

When trying to build Apache Storm downloaded from Git repository I get `storm-core` (or maybe `storm-hive`?) build error:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Storm .............................................. SUCCESS [  1.366 s]
[INFO] multilang-javascript ............................... SUCCESS [  0.801 s]
[INFO] multilang-python ................................... SUCCESS [  0.138 s]
[INFO] multilang-ruby ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.111 s]
[INFO] maven-shade-clojure-transformer .................... SUCCESS [  1.482 s]
[INFO] storm-maven-plugins ................................ SUCCESS [  1.949 s]
[INFO] Storm Core ......................................... SUCCESS [02:08 min]
[INFO] storm-rename-hack .................................. SUCCESS [  1.966 s]
[INFO] storm-kafka ........................................ SUCCESS [  3.924 s]
[INFO] storm-hdfs ......................................... SUCCESS [01:23 min]
[INFO] storm-hbase ........................................ SUCCESS [ 13.381 s]
[INFO] storm-hive ......................................... FAILURE [ 43.185 s]
[INFO] storm-jdbc ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-redis ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-eventhubs .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] flux ............................................... SKIPPED
....
....
....
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.2.1:process (default) on project storm-hive: 
Error resolving project artifact: Failure to transfer org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:pom:5.1.3-jhyde from https://clojars.org/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of clojars has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:pom:5.1.3-jhyde from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target for project org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.3-jhyde -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
....
.... 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :storm-hive
```

When running the same build with `-e` option (`mvn -e clean install -DskipTests`) I get additional info as follows:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Storm .............................................. SUCCESS [  4.136 s]
[INFO] multilang-javascript ............................... SUCCESS [  1.441 s]
[INFO] multilang-python ................................... SUCCESS [  0.151 s]
[INFO] multilang-ruby ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.150 s]
[INFO] maven-shade-clojure-transformer .................... SUCCESS [  1.915 s]
[INFO] storm-maven-plugins ................................ SUCCESS [  2.727 s]
[INFO] Storm Core ......................................... FAILURE [  9.685 s]
[INFO] storm-rename-hack .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-kafka ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-hdfs ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-hbase ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-hive ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] storm-jdbc ......................................... SKIPPED
....
....
....
....
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
....
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2.201409121644:prepare-agent (prepare-agent) on project storm-core: 
Execution prepare-agent of goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2.201409121644:prepare-agent failed: Plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2.201409121644 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
Failed to collect dependencies at org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.2.201409121644 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1 -> org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1 -> junit:junit:jar:4.8.2: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.8.2: 
Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.8.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2.201409121644:prepare-agent (prepare-agent) on project storm-core:
Execution prepare-agent of goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2.201409121644:prepare-agent failed: 
Plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.2.201409121644 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:jar:0.7.2.201409121644 -> org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1 ->
....
....
....
....
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
... 90 more
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven is trying to download jars from https repo "https://clojars.org/repo/" but java does not have client certificates. Follow below steps to import client certificates

Step 1 : Download Client Certificate

1. Open https://clojars.org/repo/ URL in the browser (i.e firefox)
2. Click on the lock icon right to the URL bar
3. Server URL is shown , click to get right arrow and then on "more information"
4. Pop-up is opened to view the certificate of the Server.
5. click on the "View Certificate", In "details" table export to a file CERT_FILE_NAME.crt

Step 2 : Import the client certificate to JDK which maven is using

keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "clojars.org" -file C:\CERT_FILE_NAME.crt -keystore C:\java\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass "changeit"

Comment: Thanks! Do I absolutely need to set password with `-storepass`? Can certificate be imported without password?

Comment: changeit is the default password of the keystore , you can ignore the option, but if promted you need to give "changeit"

Comment: When I run `C:\>keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias "clojars.org" -file e:\tmp\cl
ojure.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\security\cacerts
" -storepass "changeit"` I get:
`Certificate was added to keystore
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
\jre\lib\security\cacerts (Access denied)`

Comment: This error happens on Windows 8 , both under normal and admin accounts.

Comment: (FileNotFound) You need to give Java path in quotes as there is space in path. (Access denied) you need to run the command as admin, open cmd as administrator